# TFS 2017 "Edit project-level information" permission not working

Tags: security

Using my TFS Administrator account I have allowed the permission "Edit project-level information" for a team including my own normal account without TFS Administrator permissions.

"Edit project-level information" is described [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#project-level-permissions) and should grant the following permissions:

1. Add and administer teams and all team-related features
2. Edit check-in policies
3. Create and modify work item types, link types, categories, and process configuration
4. Create and modify areas and iterations
5. Edit shared work item queries
6. Edit team project level permission ACLs
7. Edit event subscriptions (email or SOAP) on team project level events.

From here on I have used my normal account without administrative access.

I can't guess what #1 and #6 does and can find no further documentation so any info on those two are most welcome.

I tried to add a team administrator on the teams Overview page but was deinied with the message: "Access Denied: Michael Harmsen needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit project-level information". But that is exactly the permission I have allowed.

#2: Nope. I get TF14098: Access Denied: User Michael Harmsen needs AdminProjectRights permission(s) for $/…my TFS path…

#4: Nope. When I navigate to the teams Work -> General page I get the message: “You do not have sufficient permissions to configure "team settings". You must either be a team administrator or a project administrator”. Work -> Iterations give me: “You do not have sufficient permissions to configure "iterations". You must either be a team administrator or a project administrator” and you can probably guess what message I get under Work -> Areas.

I haven’t tried #3, #5 and #7 and I’m still unsure what #1 and #6 they actually cover.

I have tried this in three different collections across two different servers both running TFS 2017 Update 1 (version 15.112.26301.0). Am I missing something or is the "Edit project-level information" just not a permission I can allow for non-administrators?

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense, the error you got just point to the user is also lacking of other permission, this does not conflict. This permission just tell you with this permission you could do something, not only with this permission you could do something. Likewise, for example #2 even if you are a team project admin without this **Edit project-level information** permission(deny for the user), you could also can't Edit check-in policies. In TFS, deny trumps allow.

Here's some things you should pay attention to before you change any permissions in TFS:

> - Permissions **allow** or **deny** users the ability to perform specific    tasks, and are usually inherited from group membership.
> - A permission that is **not set** implicitly denies users the ability    to perform tasks that require that permission, but allows
>     membership    in a group that does have that permission set to take
>     precedence,    also known as **inherited allow** and **inherited
>     deny**.
> - For almost all permissions, **deny trumps allow**, so if a user    belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set
>     to deny, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require
>     that permission even if they belong to a group that has that
>     permission set to **allow**.
> - Changing a permission for a group changes that permission for all    users who are granted that permission through their membership in
>     that group. In other words, depending on the size of the group, you
>     might affect the ability of hundreds of users to do their jobs by
>     changing just one permission. So make sure you understand the impact
>     before you make a change. Two useful tricks for understanding the
>     effects of change: **The member of** tab shows the groups that an
>     individual user or group belongs to. You can also hover over an
>     inherited permission, and a why? icon will appear. If you choose it,
>     a dialog box will open with more information.
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/change-permission-levels#a-few-things-to-know-about-permissions-in-tfs)

Comment: Hmmm...not exactly what I hoped for. I'm aware that Deny trumps Allow but I did hope that the list of items under Edit project-level information described (as the page states) "includes the ability to perform these tasks for the team project" and not "includes the ability to perform these tasks for the team project - if you also have some other permissions not described here". Now I have to combine permissions that are not described to figure out what combination actually gives permission to e.g. edit check-in policies. Quite some detective work ahead it seems. :(

Comment: This still doesn't explain why I get the error message that I need permission to edit project-level information when I have just that permission. I do not have Deny in that permission anywhere. Also: is there a delay from me granting permissions until they actually work? I can swear that I ended up with an error message that I needed permission to edit collection-level information (and have two witnesses) while trying to add someone outside the team as a Team Administrator but I could circumvent it and add the person anyway without the permission. I can't repeat it now though.

Comment: I'm heading out for vacation so unless a colleague takes over I might not look back into this for some weeks...